# AutoFixture setup interface property inside class

Tags: c#, .net, autofixture

How can I have AutoFixture populate properties in my object containing interface property?

```
public class Car : ICar
{
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public ICarinformation ContactInformation { get; set; } // problematic
            ...

public CarInformation: ICarinformation 
{
   public string Make {get; set; } // I would like these to be populated as well
   ...
```

fixture.Create() throws:

> An exception of type 'Ploeh.AutoFixture.ObjectCreationException'
>   occurred in Ploeh.AutoFixture.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: AutoFixture was unable to create an instance
>   from Mediachase.Commerce.Inventory.ICarInformation because it's an
>   interface

Is there a way to provide AutoFixture with Concrete type for that property?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, you can just use the `TypeRelay` customization

```
fixture.Customizations.Add(
    new TypeRelay(
        typeof(ICarInformation),
        typeof(CarInformation));
```

Alternatively, if you wanted to use a fake object using Moq, you could use either `AutoMoqCustomization` or `AutoConfiguredMoqCustomization`.